# A code example illustrating the difference between the paradigms of async/await and Reactive (Rx) extension?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, system.reactive, async-await, c#-5.0

Both the System.[Reactive extension for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) and [new C# 5.0 (.NET 4.5) `async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) pursue (or based on) [future and promises constructs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) paradigm (approach).

Can you give the (*) simplest C# code example illustrating the difference between them?

(*)
Is it possible without I/O, internet or database connections?

**Update:**
Well, let me reformulate if this question seemed to be answered before.
Why would one add and start using Reactive (Rx) extensions for .NET while using native .NET [Iobservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)/[IObserver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) + [await/async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx)?

What are the possible illustrations of what one will be missing from Rx that made to do the same more clumsy or less efficient without Rx (i.e. engaging just native .NET Iobservable/IObserver + await/async approach)?

Comment: Have you even googled this? Show give no indication that you have.

Comment: @fredrik, how should I prove the absence of google SERP results on it?

Comment: Just say what you have searched for and that it did not yield any result. That will show, for me, that you have at least tried.

Comment: The [closest result](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/117905/will-net-4-5-make-the-reactive-extensions-obsolete) tells why would one use await/async with Rx. But this does not answer why one would use Rx after have already been used async/await in first place

Comment: You should never use the native .NET `IObservable`/`IObserver` without Rx.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Future/Promise paradigm generally is used for returning a single value in the future. Perhaps there is some heavy calculation or IO that is required and hence why it can not be guaranteed to be return synchronously in a timely manner.

Rx (and by proxy the `IObserver<T>`/`IObservable<T>` interfaces) is a paradigm of observable sequences. Just as a synchronous method could return a single value (int), it could also return an `IEnumerable<int>` with one value. Comparing this to an asynchronous world, `Task<int>` can return a single `int` value, `IObservable<int>` could return a sequence with just one `int` value.

So if you wanted to return a sequence of values with `Task<T>`, you would have to either create some sort of continuation, or return a collection/array/list of values as the `T` e.g. `Task<int[]>`. This however will mean you get all or non of the values.

`Task`/`Task<T>` is also a concrete type, where as Rx uses interfaces to abstract you from implementation. I have found this to help in unit testing. `TaskCompletionSource<T>` however can be helpful to avoid implicit concurrency when testing with tasks.

Finally, besides the main difference that Rx is dealing with sequences of values (not single values), Rx is also designed to work with LINQ to deliver the querying and composition benefits that seems to work very well with sequences (either at rest like `IEnumerable<T>`, or in motion like `IObservable<T>`).

Ultimately these are different tools for slightly different jobs. There is some overlap, so you sometimes can use one to do what the other is better at. To be specific, I think `Task` is better at composing units of asynchronous work together (Do this, then do that, then do this), where as Rx is better at composing sequences of events together (When this event happens, do this with data from this other event).

Comment: You don't need `Task<T[]>` for multiple values, for multiple values, you can use `Task<IEnumerable<T>>` and you can also use `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface.

Comment: As pointed out "..return a collection/array/list of value..". And the discussion is not about Events (which more closely relate to RX), but about a comparison between `Rx` and `Task`. Adding events, APM, threads, callbacks and other asynchronous styles would make for a very large discussion indeed, or even a book. ;-)

Comment: “When this event happens, do this with data from this other event” that clicked on my mind really hard. I finally started getting the concept, thank you! the other day I was trying to do exactly that in React using hooks, but couldn’t figure out how to do it without sequential code, I guess I should take a look at RxJs

Answer (score 5):

They're not mutually exclusive. The main determination is whether you have a single future result or multiple future results.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-31-75-metablogapi/0815.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_59BBA077.png

Comment: +1. Also note that they work well together: `Task<T>.ToObservable()` creates an `IObservable<T>` that only produces at most a single result, and `await myObservable` allows you to asynchronously wait for the last element of an observable.

Comment: @StephenCleary, could you possibly manage to shoot the same (or the different) as an answer?

Answer (score 5):

I like the table in the Reactive documentation: http://reactivex.io/intro.html

I have my own take on it where i add a third dimension non-composable/composable.

```
Non-composable:

       |  Single Item   | Multiple items
 ------|----------------|----------------
 Sync  | Function       | Iterable
 Async | Async function | Observable

Composable:

       |      Single Item      |       Multiple items
 ------|-----------------------|----------------------------
 Sync  | Higher order function | Linq/Ramda/java.util.stream
 Async | Future/promise        | Rx observable
```

And mind you that depending on the implementation, you can have futures and rx observables that can act both synchronously or asynchronously depending on whether what you are trying to do with them is synchronous or asynchrounous